# make an intra-month sum of xts object

Tags: r, sum, xts

i have an xts object
It's a daily time series.

With endpoints(prices, 'months') i can have the position of the start and the end of every months

What i want is an xts object where every data is the sum of the daily data in every month

Which is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you posted a reproducible example of what you were trying to do, and what output you expect. Create a small example, and then post it using `dput(small_example)`.

Comment: sorry, but just now i think i found the solution. The solution is the function: apply.monthly(x,sum).